# Align 'implies' symbol to left, without disturbing equation centring

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I have a Latex document as shown in the following image: (I am using AMS Math.)

[image: what_i_have]

I want to put a `\implies` sign just before the equation e=1. But, I do not want *any other change* to occur. I am aware of simple methods using `align`, but the problem is that they change the overall centring of the math block to something like this (NOT WANTED):

[image: what_i_dont_want]

What I want is something like this:

[image: what_i_want]

The code I am using is this:

```
\subsection{Definition}
A parabola is the set of points in a plane in such a way that their distance 
from a fixed point of the plane and from a fixed line of the plane are equal.
\begin{align*}
    &\mathrm{SP} = \mathrm{PM} \\
    \implies & e = 1
\end{align*}
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\mathllap` command, from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

A parabola is the set of points in a plane in such a way that their distance
from a fixed point of the plane and from a fixed line of the plane are equal.
\begin{align*}
    &\mathrm{SP} = \mathrm{PM} \\
   \implies & e = 1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    &\mathrm{SP} = \mathrm{PM} \\
    \mathllap{\implies} & e = 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KaranKaran: What do you mean? Using `\mathllap`, so that it is considered to have 0 width, or using the command  `\implies`, or ... ?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not very good style. I would rather use a short sentence in ordinary language (`therefore` or something like that) introduced by ``intertext`/`\shortintertext`.